# How to create RAM drive?

Tags: mount, fstab, memory, tmpfs, ram-usage

How do i create RAM drive under ubuntu. And would he automounted at startup?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quote from http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/move-google-chrome-cache-to-ramdisk/:

> ```
> gksu gedit /etc/fstab
> ```
>
> Add the following line to the bottom of the text file that opens but BE CAREFUL – do not touch, edit or enter ANYTHING else:
>
> ```
> tmpfs  /media/ramdisk  tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
> ```

Comment: Txh, it was very helpful =)

Comment: What or who are you quoting?

Comment: dead link alert :)

Comment: It looks like the source was deleted / moved. But all the important stuff is written in the post above :)

Comment: Note that directory /media/ramdisk must exists of the tmpfs mount will fail. Doing `mkdir -p /media/ramdisk` once before adding the above in `fstab` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know what you mean with a RAM drive but if you mean more swapspace, you'll have to use a livecd with gparted, add a new swap partition, and then edit /etc/fstab to make the swap partition mount on boot.

Be careful, though, since making a mistake while editing fstab could have disastrous results and your system may not boot up anymore.

Also, you can mount two partitions under the same name, like swap.

Comment: It woul boot up, if backup fstab and if error occurred recover it with live cd =), but i mean a RAM-Drive, not swap or anything else. I want to take a lot of space from my RAM, and make it space as drive...