# What is the difference between initrd and initramfs?

Tags: initramfs

I would like to know, what is the difference between `initrd` and `initramfs`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Initrd is deprecated, replaced by Initramfs, which doesn't have some of the weaknesses of initrd:

- Initrd requires at least one file system driver be compiled into the kernel
- A *disk* created by Initrd has got to have a fixed size
- All of the reads/writes on Initrd are buffered redundantly (unnecessarily) into main memory

I think that's all.

---

> How does this update-initramfs command generate /boot/initrd.img?

It makes the necessary files into a `cpio`  **archive**, which is a binary archive format (very similar to `tar`, not extensively used in Linux) and then uses gzip to **compress** that archive. Gzip is not an archive itself, just a compression (which is why you get .tar.gz archive files).

At boot time, the archive is **uncompressed** and **unpacked** onto a  **[[image] ram-disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11976/how-to-create-ram-drive)**.

Also see: [How a computer boots](https://web.archive.org/web/20111130183907/http://netthink.com/?page_id=20)

Comment: "Initrd requires at least one file system driver be compiled into the kernel".. I dint get much idea on this. Could you please explain this??

Comment: Normally, File system drivers can be bolted onto the operating system at will, for some things they have to be compiled right into the kernel. Which is a pain, since all kernel versions have to be customised, get larger, introduce additional dependencies and so on. (At least that's what I believe to be the case, could well be wrong, I've not got great knowledge about file systems specifically)

Comment: Is it like initramfs need not be mounted initially??

Comment: All file systems have to be mounted before they can be used. If you want to learn about initramfs in depth, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd - there's a far more detailed explanation.

Comment: How does this update-initramfs command generate /boot/initrd.img?

Comment: @Sen edited my answer to hopefully explain that too; let me know.

Comment: @Stefano: If i want to add some more things(like GNU toolchain or some other utilities) into the initrd.img(which i think is exactly also called initramfs), how can i do that??

Answer (score 3):

- initrd was block device based, initramfs is file base.
- with initrd, you created a file system image. with initramfs, you create an archive with the files which the kernel extracts to a tmpfs.

Comment: could you please explain me the steps from the start to the loading and reading of initramfs?